# Recovering a function from its conditional expecations

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $\{ \mathcal{F}_i \}_{i \in \mathcal{I}}$ be a family of $\sigma$-subalgebras such that
$$
\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\mathcal{F}_i, i \in \mathcal{I}).
$$

**Question**

What are the conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ and $\{ \mathcal{F}_i \}_{i \in \mathcal{I}}$ such that, for all $f \in L^1$ with $E[f] = 0$, 
$$
f = \sum_i E[f|\mathcal{F}_i] \, a.s. ?
$$

Total independence of $\{ \mathcal{F}_i\}$ would perhaps suffice. Are there more general assumptions available?

Comment: Very rarely is the identity true. Examples where it fails are $\mathcal F_i=\mathcal F$ for all $i$, $\mathcal F_i$ increasing, etc. It is more natural to ask when the sequence $E(f|\mathcal F_i)$ tends to $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever be the sigma algbebras the equation fails when $f=1$.